# How to save the path of the uploaded file using uploadify after upload is complete?

Tags: wordpress, uploadify

it's been almost 2 hours that I have been browsing here at stackoverflow for answers. I have managed to make my uploading of files function well by reading some answers here. But this time can't be helped. I really need to ask on how to save the path of the uploaded file after uploading. See, I use uploadify in my wordpress plugin. What I did was save the uploaded files(.pdf to be exact) to a specific folder on my directory.Then what I want is to save the path of the saved file when the post is being published. So technically,after the upload, I want to have the path of the uploaded file somewhere in the post such that when I publish the post, the path will also be saved in the database. Is this even possible?

This is my code snippet in my plugin,

```
/* Displays the box content which is the dropdown list of Funds */
function wnm_pengana_investor_upload_investor_box( $post ) {
    /* Use nonce for verification */
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'wnm_pengana_funds_noncename' );

    echo        '<p class="uploadify_container">';
    echo            '<label style="margin-left: 15px;" for="investor_file_upload">Upload one or more files at once.</label>';
    echo            '<input type="file" name="investor_file_upload" id="investor_file_upload" />';
    echo        '</p>';
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function wnm_pengana_save_investor_upload_box( $post_id ) {
    /*verify if this is an auto save routine. If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything */
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return;

    /* verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,because save_post can be triggered at other times */
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( isset($_POST['wnm_pengana_funds_noncename']), plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    return;

    // Check permissions
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
            return;
    } else {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
    }

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    $mydata = $_POST['investor_file_upload'];


    update_post_meta($post_id, 'uploaded_forms_path', $mydata);
}
```

Currently, when published, the postmeta uploaded_forms_path will be added on the postmeta table, however it is empty. I think I need to put something after `` `echo '<input type="file" name="investor_file_upload" id="investor_file_upload" />'; ``
sadly I don't know what am I to put. Can anyone help me? Thanks.`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. It seems no one wanted to answer so I have to desperately find an answer for me.

Okay, what I did was , after saving the file, from the file uploadify.php, if the file upload is successful, I return the `$newTargetFile` such that using the onUploadSuccess event of uploadify, I can display the value of `$newTargetFile` which is the path of the uploaded file. I then assign this as a value of the hidden `<input value="$newTargetFile" />`, so when the post is being published , the data of that hidden input will be posted as postmeta data. :)